# Methods to get position of view returns 0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

This question has been asked several times, but everyone gives the reason for why this occurs (i.e. calculation occurs before the layout is laid). But I need the solution for this. I tried `getBottom();`, `getTop();`, `getLocationOnScreen(int[] location);`. But all returns the value Zero (0). I even tried giving these in `onStart();`, to give time for layout to be laid, but no luck.
Here is my code:

```
TextView tv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Log.d("getBottom   :", Integer.toString(tv.getBottom()));
    Log.d("gettop      :", Integer.toString(tv.getTop()));

    int[] location = new int[2];
    tv.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    Log.d("getlocationonscreen values :", Integer.toString(location[0])+"  "+Integer.toString(location[1]));
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Log.d("getBottom in onStart :", Integer.toString(tv.getBottom()));
    Log.d("gettop in onStart    :", Integer.toString(tv.getTop()));

    int[] location = new int[2];
    tv.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    Log.d("getlocationonscreen in onStart :", Integer.toString(location[0])+"  "+Integer.toString(location[1]));
    super.onStart();
}
```

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Again, I apologize for repeating the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain bit more what is your exact problem. what is going to wrong in above code.

Answer (score 13):

You put the 'measuring' in the [`onWindowFocusChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29)-method.
As the documentation states:

> This is the best indicator of whether this activity is visible to the user.

You could also put it in the [`onResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) which is the last step before the application is completely on screen and active, however:

> Keep in mind that onResume is not the best indicator that your activity is visible to the user; a system window such as the keyguard may be in front. Use onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) to know for certain that your activity is visible to the user (for example, to resume a game).

If the window/view has not yet been displayed there is no guarantee that it has its measurements, thus the previous method would be better.