# Dynamically call function after loading the View

Tags: android

I am new in android. My program has `setContentView(R.layout.popup)`. The xml file contains a button. I need the position of the button. For this I am using `btn_obj.getX` but it returns 0. I think I am calling this method before the contentView load. Is there any function which dynamically invokes my instruction after Loading the View?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/android-get-width-returns-0 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879504/methods-to-get-position-of-view-returns-0

Answer (score 2):

Override the [onWindowFocusChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29)

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    float x = button.getX(); // Here you can get the button X position
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`View` has the `post(Runnable)` method. You can retrieve the root layout, post a runnable on it and retrieve the position inside the runnable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are calling the `View.getX()` method in `Activity.onCreate()` in your activity. This will always return 0 because the layout of the views has not been performed yet. You can only retrieve the visual information of elements after layout. The `Activity.onStart()` method is guaranteed to be called when your activity is visible, so placing your visual-dependent code in this method is one way to achieve what you want.